Transaction proposed to Safe from Solidity doesn't appear in queue UI
I'm using a Foundry script to propose a transaction to my Gnosis safe deployed on Sepolia through web.
The flow is simple:

I correctly obtain the transaction hash with getTransactionHash(to, data);
The first owner calls appoveHash() to submit the first approval

After receiving the first hash approval, the proposed transaction should be shown in "queue" on https://app.safe.global, but it doesn't appear and therefore cannot be approved by other owners.
If, after that, I call approveHash() by the second owner (Safe is 2/2) and then execTransaction(), the transaction is correctly executed and appears int the History tab

Transactions will only appear in the queue if proposed to the transaction service.

why? I mean, it's a valid transaction proposal, shouldn't it be displayed?
